# How can I iterate through sub-elements in a list comprehension?

Tags: python, list

I have code right now to try to let me sort a dictionary by an arbitrarily deep key (like mongo), but it requires that I hard-code in how many deep the key will be.

```
#This is the code for inside the function, you need to make a function to receive the  arguments
#and the dictionary. the arguments should be listed in order of layers. It then splits the argument string
#at the "." and assigns to each of the items.From there it should return the "l[]".
#you need to set it up to pass the arguments to these appropriate spots. so the list of dicts goes to
#list and the arguments go to argstring and it should be taken care of from there.


#splitting the argument
argstring="author.age"
arglist = argstring.split(".")

x=(5-len(arglist))#need to set this number to be the most you want to accept
while x>0:
    arglist.append('')
    x-=1

#test list
list = [
{'author' : {'name':'JKRowling','age':47,'bestseller':{'series':'harrypotter','copiessold':12345}}},


{'author' : {'name':'Tolkien','age':81,'bestseller':{'series':'LOTR','copiessold':5678}}},


{'author' : {'name':'GeorgeMartin','age':64,'bestseller':{'series':'Fire&Ice','copiessold':12}}},


{'author' : {'name':'UrsulaLeGuin','age':83,'bestseller':{'series':'EarthSea', 'copiessold':444444}}}
]
l=[]#the list for returning


#determining sort algorythm
l = sorted(list, key=lambda e: e[arglist[0]][arglist[1]])#need add as many of these as necesarry to match the number above
print()
```

This works, but having to manually specify the arguments in the arglist seems silly.
If I needed 5 deep, I'd need to manually specify e 5 times..
Is there a way to use a list comprehension or for loop to automatically include arbitrary element depth?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`reduce()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce):

```
sorted(list, key=lambda e: reduce(lambda m, k: m[k], argslist, e))
```

`reduce()` takes a function, an input list and an optional initial value, and re-applies that function to then next element and the return value of the last invocation (starting with the initial value). Thus, it runs `m[k0][k1][k2]..[kn]` where the successive `k` values are taken from `argslist`.

Short demonstration:

```
>>> e = {'author' : {'name':'JKRowling','age':47,'bestseller':{'series':'harrypotter','copiessold':12345}}}
>>> argslist = ['author', 'age']
>>> reduce(lambda m, k: m[k], argslist, e)
47
```

Comment: Arg ;-).  Although I cooked it up without a `lambda`... `reduce(dict.__getitem__,'author.age'.split('.'),d)` -- +1 for beating me yet again.

Comment: @mgilson: you know, for answers like these, I prefer using a lambda. Unbound methods are very clever, and all, but require just that little more explaining. :-)

Comment: Admittedly, I sort of prefer the lambda -- I would have used it had I thought of it...

Comment: Tweak: `dict.get` instead of `dict.__getitem__`?

Comment: @DSM: No, I'd not use `dict.get`; if there is a missing key, you'd get `TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'` instead of `KeyError: 'missingkey'`. I think the latter is a *lot* easier to debug. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: good point, `__getitem__` has a better failure mode.  I just don't like looking at all those underscores.. time to take up a new language, maybe!

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with using a for loop to traverse the args

```
>>> e = {'author' : {'name':'JKRowling','age':47,'bestseller':{'series':'harrypotter','copiessold':12345}}}
>>> argslist = ['author', 'age']
>>> result = e
>>> for arg in argslist:
...     result = result[arg]
... 
>>> result
47
```

This way is really easy to debug, you can put `try/except`, `print`, breakpoints etc.